# Grafana setup on docker - not able to find Config file

Tags: docker, grafana

I am trying to setup grafana on docker using a custom grafana.ini file, however grafana is not picking up my config, I am using the command below

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 \
-v /opt/pf-grafana:/opt/pf-grafana \
grafana/grafana \
--config=/opt/pf-grafana/grafana.ini
```

I also verified that the grafana.ini file is correctly formatted. What am I missing?

Grafana.ini entry
[image]

Grafana logs
[image]

Contents of /opt/pf-grafana folder (ls from the container)
[image]

Comment: Where is your `grafana.ini` located in your Docker host machine?

Comment: yes the ini file is on my host machine

Comment: I mean **where** is it located?

Comment: My grafana.ini is located under /opt/pf-grafana/ on the host machine, i am specifying that using the "--config" flag, and the container has access to the /opt/pf-grafana folder.

Comment: What's the files under directory /opt/pf-grafa inside your container? And what's the log of your grafana?

Comment: The /opt/pf-grafana folder inside container maps to the same folder on the host, all the files on the host are visible to the container. I added screen shots in the folder and grafana logs to the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally got it working, the solution was to use environment variables, the "-e" flag overrides the default settings. The AUTH_LDAP_ENABLED and AUTH_LDAP_CONFIG_FILE are the settings in the default grafana.ini file. Note, they need to be specified in CAPS and separated by "_"

Below snippet worked for me

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 -v /opt/pf-grafana:/opt/pf-grafana \
-e "GF_AUTH_LDAP_ENABLED=true" \
-e "GF_AUTH_LDAP_CONFIG_FILE=/opt/pf-grafana/ldap.toml" \
grafana/grafana
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 \
-v /opt/pf-grafana:/opt/pf-grafana \
-v /opt/pf-grafana/grafana.ini:/etc/grafana/grafana.ini \
grafana/grafana
```

The reason:

You can't actually override the `--config` argument since it was supressed by the previous defined `--config` in [`run.sh`](https://github.com/grafana/grafana-docker/blob/ae0ca7b39861472a6c9478b2d49c78dc05b2a417/run.sh#L42) (the entrypoint of `grafana/grafana`). However, by replacing the default config file `/etc/grafana/grafana.ini` will allow you to use your own configuration instead of the default one.

Comment: I tried it, didnt work, container exits with status of 1. I also tried below command, same effect.
    `docker run -d -p 3000:3000 \
    -v /opt/pf-grafana/grafana.ini:/etc/grafana/grafana.ini \
    grafana/grafana`

Comment: Can you find out what error it is? Perhaps in the log.